# Adding a function to NodeList object doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom

I'm trying to define a function for the NodeList object. This is the code:

```
if (!NodeList.prototype.filter){
  NodeList.prototype.filter = function(fun /*, thisp*/){
    var len = this.length;
    if (typeof fun != "function")
      throw new TypeError();
    var res = new Array();
    var thisp = arguments[1];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++){
      if (i in this){
        var val = this[i]; // in case fun mutates this
        if (fun.call(thisp, val, i, this))
        res.push(val);
    }
  }
  return res;
 };  
}
```

This works in Chrome, but not in Firefox. Firebug says "current_node.childNodes.filter is not a function" when I call the function:

```
nodes = current_node.childNodes.filter(filterByClass);
```

The weird thing is that this code:

```
if(typeof NodeList.prototype.filter == 'function')
    alert(NodeList.prototype.filter);
```

displays the function's code in both browsers.

It's being used in a HTML, and it's being included like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="textselection.js"></script>
```

EDIT:
The Firefox version is 10.0.2 and the S.O. Ubuntu 11.04

EDIT2:
I had forgotten one important factor... it's being used whithin an iframe

Comment: Me too: http://jsfiddle.net/Ewupb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes made to an object's prototype in one frame are not reflected in other frames.  You'll need to include your script in every frame where you want to extend `NodeList.prototype`.

Remember that `NodeList === window.NodeList` and, in a frame, `window !== top`.  So, in a frame, `window.NodeList !== top.NodeList`.

Interestingly, for instantiable objects, like `Date`, you can still take advantage of the prototype, provided you instantiate the object by first referencing the frame with the extended prototype.  For example, if your parent frame extended `Date` to have a `.format()` method, you could do something like this from a child frame:

```
var nowString = new parent.Date().format("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss.fff TT");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very strange quirk I came across today. It seems like Firefox and Chrome don't like functions named 'filter' in HTMLCollection and NodeList particularly, although these prototypes don't seem to be using that name anyway. I renamed my custom functions to 'filt' and everything worked like charm. Btw, Safari was fine with 'filter'.

Answer (score 0):

This works in **Firefox** and **Chrome** and it's simpler:

`NodeList.prototype.myfilter = Array.prototype.filter;`

**Example:** to get all `divs` with an id attribute:

`document.querySelectorAll("div").myfilter(function(el){return el.id || 0;})`

However, you need to define `myfilter` on each frame where you are using it.